# Read DICOM objects from PosixPath, Python

Tags: python, path, pydicom

I have 20,000 PosixPath, each one pointing at a different .dcm object. I need to read .dcm objects one by one. Here is my code so far:

```
from pathlib import Path
import glob
import dicom
data = Path('/data')
path_to_dcm_objects = list(data.glob('**/*.dcm'))
for i in len(path_to_dcm_objects):
    record = dicom.read_file(path_to_dcm_objects[i])
```

I get an error when I want to read a .dcm file using its PosixPath:

```
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that didn't mean `import pydicom`?

Comment: @MikeMüller I used `pip install pydicom` to install. Then I used `import dicom` to use the module. The system does not recognize `import pydicom`

Comment: I get *This code is using an older version of pydicom, which is no longer 
maintained as of Jan 2017.  You can access the new pydicom features and API 
by installing `pydicom` from PyPI.
See 'Transitioning to pydicom 1.x' section at pydicom.readthedocs.org 
for more information.*

Comment: @MikeMüller I will check that out. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dicom.read_file()` needs an open file object or a string for the path not a `Path` instance. If it is not a strings it considers it an open file and tries to read from it.

Convert the `Path` instance to a string with `str(path_object)`:

```
for i in len(path_to_dcm_objects):
    record = dicom.read_file(str(path_to_dcm_objects[i]))
```

The help for converting a `Path` object into a string:

> Return the string representation of the path, suitable for
>   passing to system calls.

You can also use:

```
 path_object.as_posix()
```

This gives you a Posix path:

> Return the string representation of the path with forward (/)
>   slashes.

BTW, the pythonic way to iterate over all paths would look more like this:

```
for path_obj in data.glob('**/*.dcm'):
    record = dicom.read_file(str(path_obj))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I appreciate it!